# Dropbox JS SDK: Combine filesListFolder with retrieving link

Tags: javascript, sdk, dropbox, dropbox-api

I just started working with the [Dropbox JavaScript SDK](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/) to list product sheets on a WordPress project. It have started out great with listing the corresponding PDF files matching the product title (code further down), but I want to retrieve a public link for people to download it. I started looking at an example included in the SDK, but it requires a shared link – which is what I want to retrieve, right (not sure if I've mixed up the terms)? The object output doesn't include a shared link, but an ID and a relative path, if that helps.

### Current code:

```
function listFiles() {
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = '*******';
    var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
    dbx.filesListFolder({path: '/Product Data Sheet/<?php echo $dbx_line; ?>/<?php echo $dbx_category; ?>/<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME_EN; ?>/'})
    .then(function(response) {
        displayFiles(response.entries);
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
    return false;
}

function displayFiles(files) {
    var filesList = document.getElementById('files');
    var li;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        var name = files[i].name.slice(4).slice(0, -7),
                name = name.replace('_', '/');
        if( name === '<?php echo $dbx_name; ?>') {
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
            filesList.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}

listFiles();
```

JS console output:

[image]

Comment: You can use [`sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings__anchor) to create a publicly-accessible shared link for any particular file or folder as specified by path.

Comment: @Greg an example would be helpful

Comment: @Miraz I've answered your new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558459/get-link-to-the-uploaded-image-in-dropbox-using-js-and-sdk

Answer (score 3):

The new Dropbox API is poorly documented - I just spent a day or so on it.

1) Your list files looks good

```
var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
dbx.filesListFolder({path: ""})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

The result is similar to the following

```
{
"entries": [
    {
        ".tag": "folder",
        "name": "Apps",
        "path_lower": "/apps",
        "path_display": "/Apps",
        "id": "id:XYZ",
        "$$hashKey": "object:175"
    },
    {
        ".tag": "file",
        "name": "Getting Started with Dropbox.pdf",
        "path_lower": "/getting started with dropbox.pdf",
        "path_display": "/Getting Started with Dropbox.pdf",
        "id": "id:XYZ",
        "client_modified": "2016-04-10T19:24:04Z",
        "server_modified": "2016-04-10T19:24:01Z",
        "rev": "14703ce11",
        "size": 1142545,
        "$$hashKey": "object:180"
    }
],
"cursor": "XYZ",
"has_more": false
}
```

2) Now use the above to create a shared link for the file (The doc says that it will just return the link if one exists).

Note>> I'm not sure pathLower is needed but I just assumed it was

```
  dbx.sharingCreateSharedLink({path: **pathLower_to_your_file**})
  .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.url);
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
  });

};
```

This will produce something like the following

```
{
    ".tag": "file",
    "url": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/**your  id**/Getting%20Started%20with%20Dropbox.pdf?dl=0",
... // omitted for brevity
}
```

3) Finally you can retrieve the file using the URL e.g.

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/**your  id**/Getting%20Started%20with%20Dropbox.pdf?dl=0
```

** further work on this showed that dropbox uses HTTP forwarding and node request has a problem with this. I used fetch and it worked like a charm with forwarding https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

```
fetch(req.body.url, {
    method: 'GET'
    , redirect: 'follow'
    , follow: 20
    , timeout: 0
})
.then(function(res) {
    s3.createBucket(bucket_params, function(err) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
        var s3obj = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: bucket_name, Key: file_name}});
        s3obj.upload({Body: res.body}).
       on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); }).
       send(function(err, data) {
           if(err){
              console.log("error uploading data" + err);
           }else {
              console.log("Success!!!!!") }
       })
    }
  });

});
```